# Customize proof environment in AMSART (from italics to boldface)

Tags: amsmath, amsart

In `amsart`, I used

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\oldproofname=\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{\oldproofname}}
```

to change the *Proof* heading from italics to boldface. However, when I write, for instance,

```
\begin{proof}[Proof of X's Lemma]
```

I get the output *Proof of X's Lemma* in italics and not in boldface. How can I fix this (and possibly improve the trick above)?

Comment: not directly relevant to the question, but ... the features of `amsthm` are built into `amsart` (and all the ams document classes), so it isn't necessary to specify that with `\usepackage`, and doing that has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to patch `\proof` to substitute `\itshape` for `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}
  {\itshape}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
test
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[A test proof]
test
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the period after the head in bold-face font, the patch would be

```
\xpatchcmd{\proof}
  {\itshape#1}
  {{\bfseries#1}}
  {}
  {}
```